# Can't get the background color using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to get element background style which has been written on a different CSS file.
The problem is that I can't get the style which were written in a CSS file.

on the other hand, styling which has been written on the HTML document are possible to get.

#### CSS code

```
#try2
{ 
    background-color:yellow;
}
body
{
    background-color:gray;
}
td, th{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

#### HTML code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="html.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id = "try1" style="background-color:green;"><p id="ChosenColor3"> htmlfile</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id = "try2"><p id="ChosenColor4"> css file</p></td>
                <td><button id="bestRated3" onclick = arrayTest()> ב.מ </button></td>
                <td><button id="submitForm" onclick = submit()> end</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h1 id="ChosenColor5"> text </h1></td>  
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    <script>
        window.onload=aaa();
        function aaa()
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("try2");
            alert(x.style.background);
        }
    </script>     
</html>
```

As you can see, the message I get is empty. If I will change the ID to "`try1`" it will be displayed.

Comment: Should write `window.onload=aaa;`. `#try2` does not have `style` attribute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`style`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-ElementCSSInlineStyle) property lets you read and write the value for each element's `style` HTML attribute (what is called its *inline style*) -- it does not take stylesheets into account.

To discover what the *real* value of a CSS attribute is you have to use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) instead, for example:

```
alert(getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue("background-color"));
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/6NxUU/)**.

Please note that `getComputedStyle` is not supported by IE 8 or earlier.

Comment: ... but IE <= 8 does have `x.currentStyle`, which is roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Change your alert to `alert(x.style.backgroundColor);`

`style.background` and `style.backgroundColor` are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   function aaa()
        {
           var a = document.getElementById("try2").style.backgroundcolor;
           alert("Your background color is :"+a);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
alert(x.style.backgroundColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned the value for background. So use something like this:

```
alert(x.style.background="red");
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/bSxaC/)

Comment: You missed 'e'. Also, it's 2013 so you could at least use `console.log` as it's more user friendly than alerts. Or even better, could've added a `div` and just changed `innerHTML`.